# Why does Apache Kafka need an internet connection run locally?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm running `Apache Kafka` on my `local machine` and observed that: When I turn on my Wi-Fi connection Apache Kafka Server starts throwing exceptions and then stops.

```
NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:945) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$600(NetworkClient.java:68) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1114) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1005) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:537) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:331) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238) [kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.j
```

What does Kafka need an internet connection for? Considering I'm running my server locally?

Comment: It needs to be able to communicate with Zookeeper over a network interface, not "the Internet". If you turn off the network adapter, the application wouldn't know how to route requests

Comment: Hey @cricket_007, that makes sense, Thanks.